# Python pdb -- how to change the default lines listed by "l" command?

Tags: python, list, line, default, pdb

I'm experimenting with debugging my python from the raw pdb program rather than running pdb though emacs (which tracks the current line with a marker in the text display of the code).  It's slightly annoying that the list command l in pdb only displays a few lines of code, I would rather have it fill my terminal with all the code of the current function up to the current line.

I know I can do this manually by looking at the line numbers are typing l 50,100 (where 100 is the current line) but this is time consuming and I'd like to set this up to work automatically.

I wonder if there is a way to define a pdb command to do this?   I'm guessing it would need to (1) access the number of the current line, N; then (2) execute "l N-50, N".  I've searched around a lot but can't find anyone who has done this before.  Perhaps there is a way to access the pdb module's own internals to get the line number?

(Or a roundabout way would be to write something that calls list once, parses the output to extract the current line, then executes a new list command, I wonder if anyone has done this already?   Is this how IDEs manage to get the current line information from pdb or are they using its internals I wonder?)

Comment: (I just found a way to do this by hacking /usr/lib/python2.7/pdb.py , the source code of the debugger itself.  The function do_list in there has variables first and last which are line numbers to list.  Looks like they are hardcoded into the debugger but can be hacked in place.   I still wonder if there is a nicer way to do this, or if it would be useful to patch the pdb source to create one?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably extend the PDB class, but the extension interface isn't documented very well.

I'd instead recommend using [pdb++](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdbpp/) and its **sticky** feature which pretty much does what you want, if I understood your use case correctly.

Comment: Thanks Lucas this looks interesting -- I also found xpdb (http://heather.cs.ucdavis.edu/~matloff/xpdb.html) which looks like a similar project.